# How to restrict Service accounts from performing a code review?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to restrict code reviews being assigned to a "Service account" in in Azure DEVOPS?

Comment: Widened the tag to get more coverage

Comment: May I know how's this things going after the weekend? Does below work around is work for you?

Comment: Hi thanks it works however the gated build fails with the error that : read permission required to retrieve the content. Is there an alternative way to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct permission node can make you achieve the code review restrict.

But since the prerequisite for `Code review` is that you must have **Read** Repos files permissions, you can make use of one work around: restrict its `Read` permission of repos.

To better manage the service accounts you mentioned, you can add them into one group firstly. (Here name it `Service` group)

Then go **Project setting** -> **Repositories**, click on the `Git repositories` or `one specified repos` (*this depend on which repos's code review you want to restrict*).

Search and add the `Service` group, and then set its `Read` permission as **Deny**.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks it works however the gated build fails with the error that : read permission required to retrieve the content. Is there an alternative way to enable this?

Comment: @user12810368, I'm afraid not, you know, there's no direct permission set for code review. Every security has its corresponding secure model, but it does not contain code review. My suggestion is a work around which can get the same work. Also, as the error you meet, it is caused by pipeline is using service accounts to do corresponding operation. But here we restrict its permission. Can I know, you want service accounts has no code review ability? Or just some collection level service account.

Comment: The service account we are using is also the build administrator account which is used for.build and release